# How To Reduce Thrift Bloat

Tags: java, android, thrift

I'm currently trying to reduce my method count for an Android App so as to get it compiling again. One of the areas I'd like to improve upon is all the thrift generated files that are being used. It's insane how overly bloated simple thrift structs become.

For example this following thrift struct:

```
struct AccessoryLocalization {
    1: required string displayName;
    2: required string displaySummary;
}
```

Turns into a 475 lined java class!!! That seems insane to me, and I'm not totally understanding why it's generating so much.  I am wondering if anyone knew of any way to get thrift to not be so verbose in their code generation.

I'm using Thrift 0.9.0 and using the `java:android_legacy` flag when running the thrift commands. I'm only concerned about supporting Gingerbread and up.

Comment: maybe a tool like Proguard can help?

Comment: You are right, and I agree that there are some parts of the generated code could be less verbose. But OTOH generated code in general (not only with Thrift) is **not** intended to read it line by line and/or print it out. **The primary goal is to have correctly working and blazingly fast code.** -> May I ask what exactly the issue is, besides being concerned about somewhat larger files? If there is a (real) issue, we should do sth. about it. I would suggest to start a thread in the mailing list, discussing the parts that you find unnecessary, bloated or simply overly verbose.

Comment: The primary issue is that in Android there is a 64k limit on the number of methods allowed in a given app. It isn't hard to reach when you start including multiple huge libraries: Eg AWS, Google Play Services, Google Analytics, etc. There are some ways to work around the problem but ultimately it's a pain. Even if one makes it under the method limit, you still have dalvik's linearalloc buffer limits...especially troublesome on gingerbread. Having a ton of thrift bloat would seem like an easy way to help mitigate these issues.

Comment: Proguard can help somewhat, but its hard to dev if all your builds are  obfuscated release builds.

Comment: @Jay Soyer you can add a -dontobfuscate option to it won't do that. That allows you to use it as a purely optimizing tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is definitely an old question, but this week I released an Android-specific Thrift compiler and runtime that addresses these exact concerns:

https://github.com/Microsoft/thrifty

It generates code that

1. uses as few methods as possible - no getters/setters/isSetters/setIsSetters
2. is friendlier to Proguard (no storing pseudo-reflection TFields in static maps)
3. offers a few Android-specific options like `@Nullable`/`@NonNull` annotations

It took our app from 20K methods of Thrift classes to 5K.  Hopefully it can help you (or others who find this question).